# css transition for page transitioin not triggering

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a page transition I'm trying to work into my site. I have 2 50% height, 100% width elements, one placed before and after the body (with pseudo-selectors). I would like the 2 elements to slide to the middle of the screen, covering the background content. The transition is triggered when the "is-changing" class is added to the body, via Javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", fakeReq);

function fakeReq() {
  let body = document.body;
  body.classList.add("is-changing");
  console.log("class added");
  setTimeout(function() {
    body.classList.remove("is-changing");
    console.log("class removed");
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey; 
}

main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
}


body::after, body::before {
 height: 50vh; 
 width: 100%; 
 position: fixed; 
 left: 0; 
 background-color: blue; 
 z-index: 10; 

}

body::before {
 top: 0; 
 transform: translateY(-100%); 
}

body::after {
 bottom: 0; 
 transform: translateY(100%);
}

body.is-changing::after, body.is-changing::before {
 transform: translateY(0); 
}

.loading-bar {
 position: fixed; 
 height: 2px; 
 width: 90%; 
}

.loading-bar::before {
 position: absolute; 
 background-color: aqua; 
 left: 0; 
 top: 0; 
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%; 
 transform: scaleX(0);
 transform-origin: left center; 
}

.is-changing .loading-bar::before {
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="index main-content">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <button id="btn">html request</button>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: you need `content:""` for pseudo element and you need to add transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're running into two issues.

The first issue is that you forgot to include the `content` attribute in your pseudo elements (often this will be empty, like `content: ""`). Without this attribute, your pseudo elements will not exist in the DOM. Running your code snippet and inspecting it confirms this, since the pseudo elements are nowhere to be found.

Second, you're creating multiple pseudo elements. `body::before` is it's own pseudo element, and `body.is-changing::before` is a separate pseudo element. If you are hoping to create a constant set of elements that act as "doors" for a loading display, you may want to consider creating two real elements that sit in `position: fixed` above and below the viewport, and then slide in or out when a class is added. Perhaps these could be `div.upper-door` and `div.lower-door`.

Also, it looks to me like you're in need of a transition for your transform, or else the pseudo elements will just "snap" back and forth. You can take control of the position of your elements at different points during this transition by using a css animation. Your JavaScript would largely remain the same, except for targeting the `.upper-door` and `.lower-door` divs using `document.querySelector()`, or simply using IDs rather than classes and targeting with `getElementById()`, if that makes more sense for you. Your css might look like this:

```
div.upper-door {
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

div.upper-door.is-changing {
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-name: upper-door-closeopen;
}

div.lower-door {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

div.lower-door.is-changing {
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-name: lower-door-closeopen;
}

@keyframes upper-door-closeopen {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
}

@keyframes lower-door-closeopen {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
}
```

The css animation will be triggered when `.is-changing` is added to the element. As you experiment, you may find different permutations of this solution (such as using event listeners if a button click is triggering the loading screen) to be ideal.

There is a great resource on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) for css animations if you would like more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", fakeReq);

function fakeReq() {
  let body = document.body;
  body.classList.add("is-changing");
  console.log("class added");
  setTimeout(function() {
    body.classList.remove("is-changing");
    console.log("class removed");
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey; 
}

main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
}


body::after, body::before {
content:'';
 height: 50vh; 
 width: 100%; 
 position: fixed; 
 left: 0; 
 background-color: blue; 
 z-index: 10; 

}

body::before {
content:'';
 top: 0; 
 transform: translateY(-100%); 
  transition: .5s all;
}

body::after {
content:'';
 bottom: 0; 
 transform: translateY(100%);
}

body.is-changing::after, body.is-changing::before {
content:'';
 transform: translateY(0); 
}

.loading-bar {
 position: fixed; 
 height: 2px; 
 width: 90%; 
}

.loading-bar::before {
content:'';
 position: absolute; 
 background-color: aqua; 
 left: 0; 
 top: 0; 
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%; 
 transform: scaleX(0);
 transform-origin: left center; 
}

.is-changing,.loading-bar::before {
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="index main-content">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <button id="btn">html request</button>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add the `content` property on the `pseudo-elements` which is **mandatory** to make them available on the page. You also missed to add the `transition` property on the `pseudo-elements` to achieve your animation of sliding up/down.

Here's a snippet containing a working demo, I only used the code that is related to your issue:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", fakeReq);

function fakeReq() {
  let body = document.body;
  body.classList.add("is-changing");
  console.log("class added");
  setTimeout(function() {
    body.classList.remove("is-changing");
    console.log("class removed");
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative; /* not really related to your issue but, to make sure that the body's pseudo-elements are positioned relative to the body */
}

main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
}


body::after, body::before {
    content: ""; /* make the pseudo-elements available */
 height: 50vh; 
 width: 100%; 
 position: fixed; 
 left: 0; 
 background-color: blue; 
 z-index: 10; 
    transition: all .8s ease-out; /* allow the animation, change this rule per your requirements */
}

body::before {
 top: 0; 
 transform: translateY(-100%); 
}

body::after {
 bottom: 0; 
 transform: translateY(100%);
}

body.is-changing::after, body.is-changing::before {
 transform: translateY(0); 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="index main-content">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <button id="btn">html request</button>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) about `after` pseudo-element.
>
> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) about `before` pseudo-element.